# Spring form:select cats as toString

Tags: java, spring, forms, select, model-view-controller

Could you please give me an idea what goes wrong with the code? I try to iterate through the List of objects in spring mvc's select. The result should be concatenation of two bean's fileds which are retrieved through getDisplayName(). But the result of this method in the jsp looks like result of toString() - org.financespring.model.Client@1aaed9a9. Thank you for assistance. The code is below:

**.jsp**

```
<body>
    <form:form action="newclientpage" method="post" modelAttribute="client">
        <div id="client-buttons">
            <input type="button" name="client-action" value="Add Client">
            <input type="button" name="client-action" value="Del Client">
            <input type="button" name="client-action" value="Edit Client">
            <input type="button" name="client-action" value="Show client details">
        </div>
        <form:select path="displayName" items="${listOfClients}" size="25" width="200px"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initNewClientForm(ModelMap model) {
        Client client = new Client();
        List<Client> listOfClients = clientService.getListOfClients();
        model.addAttribute("client", client);
        model.addAttribute("listOfClients", listOfClients);
        return "clientpage";
    }
```

**Bean**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "postal_code", nullable = false)
    private String postalCode;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't overload toString() in Client?

Comment: No. But why should I do that? Why the method returns string presentation of the Client-object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your list like that:

```
<form:select path="displayName">
    <form:options items="${listOfClients}" itemValue="displayName" itemLabel="displayName" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thank you! But why in my case the method acts as toString()?

Comment: By default it expects a string value, and since you did not provide any it tries to convert object to string i guess.

Comment: I got that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through your list of Clients and make a new list that only contains the display name , and then use this list for your select in the jsp file.

```
List<String> displayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Client c : listOfClients)
    displayNames.add(c.getDisplayName());
model.addAttribute("listOfDisplayNames", displayNames);
```

Comment: Yes, it works too. But I was looking for more elegant way to do it. Anyway, thank you.